# Web Scraping - xPath issue

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I need to extract the text `120` from this HTML code:

```
<section class="details">
    <h2>Détails du bien</h2>

        <table>
            ....
            <tr>
                <td>Surface habitable (m²)</td>
                <td class="right" title="120">120 </td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </table>
</section>
```

I used this xpath, but it returns an empty list:

```
//td[contains(text(),"Surface")]/td[@class="right"]/text()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [xPath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp):

`//td[contains(text(),"Surface")]/following-sibling::td[@class="right"]/text()`

This should solve your problem.